# add css dynamically to rows 4 to 6

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help to add dynamic css value anim-section to row 4 to 6 as shown below

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 zoom">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 zoom">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 zoom">3</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 anim-section zoom">4</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 anim-section zoom">5</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 anim-section zoom">6</div>
```

I tried this but nothing happened- I am lost

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.col-xs-12.col-sm-4.zoom div:nth-child(n+3)').addClass('anim-section');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working perfectly..see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/w9jh0bnt/)

Comment: your zoom does not seem to be having child `div`.. :(

Comment: the anim-section class is already appended to the divs

Comment: @Lal he is making a mistake by searching child div I think..

Comment: yeah I understood.. but that fiddle works...do you know why that happens @whatever

Comment: @Lal it happens because he already add classes to html element .. so js is useless   http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/w9jh0bnt/1/

Comment: uff..ooopss..didnt notice that..thanks @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @Lal believe it or not  .. I tried that before you and ask myself the same question is his code is work till I got that point .. but keep it a secret :)

Comment: :D sure it'l be a secret.. @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes nice point.. Sure it is a secret..

Comment: @Lai   , whatever .. oh no . .. Please guys don't tell CNN about that :) .. what a secret is that LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st: `jQuery('.col-xs-12.col-sm-4.zoom div:nth-child(n+3)')` space in selector is wrong you should read about [**selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) .. space mean find children with .. so you have to use `jQuery('.col-xs-12.col-sm-4.zoom:nth-child(n+4)')`  instead

you can use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.col-xs-12.col-sm-4.zoom:nth-child(n+4)').addClass('anim-section');
    });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8s7bgej4/)

Answer (score 1):

try jquery [`slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.col-xs-12').slice(-3).addClass('anim-section');// or .slice(3,6)
    });
    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dy988q4j/